# POST to REST server by php

Tags: php, post, curl

I want to make a post to a server I have by using php.

I was thinking in curl but all examples I find, urlfy data and I have to send a json file but not in the url.

I already have the json in an array : 'key'=>'value'...

I have to add headers, I think I can with this:

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('HeaderName: HeaderValue','HeaderName2: HeaderValue2'));
```

but I don't knoe how to add my array and post it.

Any idea?

I need to add a json like this:

```
[{"a":"q",
  "b":"w",
  "c":[{
        "e":"w",
         "r":"t"
      }]
}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how you can post the data using CURL, and as you mentioned you already have a json you can do so as

```
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'your api end point');
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postfields); // $postfields is the json that you have
$request_headers = array();
$request_headers[] = 'HeaderName: HeaderValue','HeaderName2: HeaderValue2';
$request_headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/json','Content-Length: ' . strlen($postfields) ;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $request_headers); 
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: do I have to convert array to string or $postfields is in array form?

Comment: No you do not need to convert that to array you can pass json provided the api end point accept json data as request. The above code is from one of the API that I am working on and the API accepts JSON string as request. My API end point reads the JSON as `json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true)`

Comment: Thanks I will try in a few minutes

Comment: I have a problem. I am waiting a json but with [ ] in the other side, because I can send many json together. How can I add that braquets?

Comment: Please add some example in the question how you are generating the JSON. Using [] makes it an array and in this case you do not need to add the content type on the header rest all should be same.

Comment: I added an example of json. As I just add one element inside "c", it doesn't add brackets. I already got external brackets by using json_encode

Comment: I just solved. I have to create another array and then add it to the first one as one element. Thanks for curl help man!